# $f_n + g_n \rightarrow f + g $. Now my question is that Is it true that $f_ng_n \rightarrow f.g $?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $f_n \rightarrow f $ and $ g_n \rightarrow g$ and $f_n + g_n \rightarrow f + g $.

Now my question is that

Is it true that $f_ng_n  \rightarrow f.g $ ?

## My attempt  : I thinks it will be true, that is

$|f_n(x)g_n(x) -f(x)g(x)|\le |f_n(x) -f(x)||g_n(x)| + |g_n(x) -g(x)||f(x)| < \epsilon$

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Which topology?  For example, it is not true that $f_ng_n\to fg$ in the uniform topology on $\mathbb{R^R}$ if $f_n\to f$ and $g_n\to g$

Comment: @user10354138..on usual topology

Comment: Can't you just take logs?  $ln(f_n g_n)= ln(f_n) + ln(g_n)  -> ln(f) + ln(g) = ln(fg) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea for the proof.

Make sure that you use the fact that convergence sequences are bonded to finish it.